# How to shift every value of selected rows by one place in pandas

Tags: pandas

[image]

In the pandas dataframe I need to shift all the values in every seventh row (every Saturday) by one place, so that all the 10s line up vertically.

So 2020-11-07
should go from

```
10  1   10  3   10  9   10  7   10  3   10  5   10  5   10  10
```

to

```
10  10  1   10  3   10  9   10  7   10  3   10  5   10  5   10
```

And likewise for 2020-11-14, 2020-11-21 etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For every 7th row in the dataframe, use [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) method to move everything right by one place and then concatenate the last value and everything from the shifted row except the first one (which will be *null*)

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if i % 6 == 0:
        df.iloc[i, :] = [df.iloc[i, -1]] + df.iloc[i, :].shift(1).tolist()[1:]
```

If needed, this solution can be generalized to shift every *k*th row by *r* places

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if i % (k-1) == 0:
        df.iloc[i, :] = df.iloc[i, -r:].tolist() + df.iloc[i, :].shift(r).tolist()[r:]
```

**EDIT:**

You can achieve this also without using the `shift` method

For every 7th row 1 place:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if i % 6 == 0:
        df.iloc[i, :] = [df.iloc[i, -1]] + df.iloc[i, :-1].tolist()
```

For the general case of *k*th row *r* places:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if i % (k-1) == 0:
        df.iloc[i, :] = df.iloc[i, -r:].tolist() + df.iloc[i, :-r].tolist()
```

Comment: Yes! This is what I wanted :) thank you. Apparently I don't have enough XP in here to upvote you.

Answer (score -2):

Do you want something like this ?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Build a little exemple (with only 2 columns)
rng = pd.date_range('2021-11-01', periods=15, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng, '1': range(15), '2':range(15) })
df["2"] = df["2"] * 100

# Algo :
# creat a new column with the max hour+1
df["3"] = np.NaN

for i in [2,1]:
    # Increment hour every sunday (day 6, because starting at 0) 
     df[str(i+1)] = df[str(i)].where(df["Date"].dt.weekday == 6, df[str(i+1)])

    # Last hour become first hour every sunday
    df[str(1)] = df[str(3)].where(df["Date"].dt.weekday == 6, df[str(1)])
#EndFor

# Keep only first columns
df = df[["Date", "1", "2"]]
```

Result :

```
         Date       1     2
0  2021-11-01     0.0     0
1  2021-11-02     1.0   100
2  2021-11-03     2.0   200
3  2021-11-04     3.0   300
4  2021-11-05     4.0   400
5  2021-11-06     5.0   500
6  2021-11-07   600.0     6
7  2021-11-08     7.0   700
8  2021-11-09     8.0   800
9  2021-11-10     9.0   900
10 2021-11-11    10.0  1000
11 2021-11-12    11.0  1100
12 2021-11-13    12.0  1200
13 2021-11-14  1300.0    13
14 2021-11-15    14.0  1400
```

This is not the best way to get the result, but this is one.